# Is there a way in Python to start a variable at 0 and then increment by 1 while in a for loop?

Tags: python, increment

Below is a section of my code and I am attempting to start with day at 0 then 1, 2, 3, 4 so there are 5 total days, just starting at 0. Is there an easy way to do this because at the moment I am only having days 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 since I have `day = day + 1` which doesn't allow to have a day of 0? Sorry if this is a silly question, I am still relatively new to learning Python.

```
density = np.zeros((6, 91, 181))
day = 0
for i,e in df.iterrows():
    lat = int((e['Latitude']+90)/2)
    long = int(e['Longitude']/2)
    if lat == 0.0 and long == 0.0:
        day = day + 1
        print(day)
    density[day,lat,long] = e['rho']
```

Comment: If your `if` statement isn't met you will start with `day = 0`

Comment: You could set ```day = -1``` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what you want to achieve, but if you'd initialise day with -1 instead of 0, wouldn't that solve your problem?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26857780)

Comment: Well, it addresses the described problem. But you are right ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`range()` produces an iterable object which you can use for this purpose, starting at 0 and ending at whatever value you specify:

```
density = np.zeros((6, 91, 181))
days = range(5)                      # assign days to be an iterator, e.g. range()
for i,e in df.iterrows():
    lat = int((e['Latitude']+90)/2)
    long = int(e['Longitude']/2)
    if lat == 0.0 and long == 0.0:
        day = next(days)             # assign day by popping the first value from that iterator
        print(day)
    density[day,lat,long] = e['rho']
```

If you instead want an infinite list of numbers ascending from zero, you can make your own infinite number generator:

```
def inf_ints():
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield i
        i += 1

...
days = inf_ints()
...
```